# ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_20 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (2,)

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, image-recognition

So I'm trying to perform binary classification with a keras CNN. I'm getting the following error when trying to fit my model to a generator. Here is the generator:

```
image_gen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rotation_range=30, 
    width_shift_range=0.1,
    height_shift_range=0.1, 
    horizontal_flip=True,
    rescale=1/255)

training_generator = image_gen.flow_from_directory('dataset/DATASET/TRAIN',target_size=(300,300))
```

Here is my model:

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(filters=32,kernel_size=(4,4),input_shape=(300,300,3),activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=32,kernel_size=(4,4),input_shape=(300,300),activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=64,kernel_size=(3,3),input_shape=(300,300,3),activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=64,kernel_size=(3,3),input_shape=(300,300,3),activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(units=128,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(units=64,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(rate=0.35))
model.add(Dense(units=32,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(units=1,activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit_generator(training_generator,epochs=5)
```

Here is the error:
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_24 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (2,)

I've attached a screenshot of the model summary
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is specific to binary classification where `ImageDataGenerator` is used without specifying `class_mode` as 'binary`.

In the following line you need to add `class_mode` as mentioned above.

```
training_generator = image_gen.flow_from_directory('dataset/DATASET/TRAIN',target_size=(300,300),class_mode='binary')
```

`class_mode` must be specified for binary classification. If you are using keras then it will throw an error saying that `expected dense_2 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (2,)`

If you are using tf.keras then it will *NOT* throw an error but the classification accuracy will be shown as 50%.

I have taken `cats vs dogs` binary classification example to demonstrate the issue. Full code is [here](https://github.com/jvishnuvardhan/Stackoverflow_Questions/blob/master/Binary_classification_datagenerator.ipynb).